# Зацикливание процесса обучения нейронной сети

Tags: python, нейронные-сети

Написал перцептрон с одним скрытым слоем, он в малом процете случаев обучаем операции xor.
На википедии в статье [Теорема Розенблатта](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B5%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0_%D1%81%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8_%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0) пишутся следующие утверждения:

**Цитата 1**

> каждый стимул должен возбуждать по крайней мере один А-элемент.

Следующее утверждение просьба прояснить (что такое коэффициент смещения - понял):
**Цитата 2**

> не должно существовать никакой подпоследовательности стимулов, содержащей по меньшей мере по одному стимулу каждого класса, которая приводила бы к одинаковому коэффициенту смещения для каждого А-элемента в множестве А-элементов, реагирующих на эту подпоследовательность.

Он не должен быть одинаковым у всех A-элементов для некоторой последовательности обучающей выборки? Это как-то можно учитывать при генерировании начального состояния перцептрона?

И при этом там же пишется:

**Цитата 3**

> Даны элементарный перцептрон, пространство стимулов W и некоторая классификация C(W), для которой известно, что решение существует. Предположим, что все стимулы из W появляются в любой последовательности, но при условии, что каждый стимул появляется повторно через некоторый конечный интервал времени. Тогда процесс обучения с коррекцией ошибок (с квантованием или без квантования подкрепления), начинающийся с произвольного исходного состояния, всегда приведёт к достижению решения для C(W) в течение конечного промежутка времени. При этом все входные сигналы к R - элементам достигнут значения, по крайней мере равного некоторой произвольной величине d >= 0.

При наблюдении за процессом обучения (обучение происходит, пока сеть даёт неправильные ответы), не учитывая вариант, когда какой-то образец не активирует ни одного А-элемента, чаще всего наблюдается ситуация, когда на некотором этапе сеть приходит в состояние, в котором уже была, и процесс повторяется. Пример:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код нейронной сети:

```
class Perceptron(object):
    def __init__(self, input_signal_count, hidden_layer_size):
        """
        Initializes perceptron
        """
        self.input_signal_count = input_signal_count
        self.hidden_layer_size = hidden_layer_size
        self.connections_to_hidden_layer = self.init_connections_hidden_layer()
        self.hidden_layer_boundries = self.init_hidden_layer_boundries()
        self.hidden_layer_weights = self.init_hidden_layer_weights()

    def init_connections_hidden_layer(self):
        all_signals_connections = [] #[[-1, 1, 1], [1, -1, 1]]
        for signal_indx in range(self.input_signal_count):
            signal_connections = [random.choice([-1, 1]) for i in range(self.hidden_layer_size)]#random.randint(-1, 1) for i in range(self.hidden_layer_size)]
            all_signals_connections.append(signal_connections)

        return all_signals_connections

    def init_hidden_layer_boundries(self):
        hidden_layer_boundries = [0 for i in range(self.hidden_layer_size)] #[random.randint(-self.input_signal_count, self.input_signal_count - 1)
                                  # for i in range(self.hidden_layer_size)]
        return hidden_layer_boundries

    def init_hidden_layer_weights(self):
        #return [2, 2, -1]
        return [random.randint(-7, 7) for i in range(self.hidden_layer_size)]

    def get_hidden_layer_values(self, input_signals):
        assert len(input_signals) == self.input_signal_count

        hidden_layer_inputs = [0 for i in range(self.hidden_layer_size)]
        for input_signal_indx in range(self.input_signal_count):
            for hidden_neuron_indx in range(self.hidden_layer_size):
                hidden_layer_inputs[hidden_neuron_indx] += \
                    self.connections_to_hidden_layer[input_signal_indx][hidden_neuron_indx] \
                    * input_signals[input_signal_indx]
        return hidden_layer_inputs

    def calc_activated_hidden_neurons(self, hidden_layer_inputs):
        assert len(hidden_layer_inputs) == self.hidden_layer_size

        hidden_neuron_boundries_reached = [hidden_layer_inputs[i] >= self.hidden_layer_boundries[i]
                                           for i in range(self.hidden_layer_size)]
        return hidden_neuron_boundries_reached

    def get_answer(self, input_signals):
        assert len(input_signals) == self.input_signal_count

        hidden_layer_inputs = self.get_hidden_layer_values(input_signals)
        activated_hidden_neurons = self.calc_activated_hidden_neurons(hidden_layer_inputs)

        if True not in activated_hidden_neurons:
            print('Error: no activated hidden neurons on input ' + str(input_signals))

        sum = 0

        for i in range(self.hidden_layer_size):
            boundry_reached = activated_hidden_neurons[i]
            if boundry_reached:
                hidden_neuron_val = hidden_layer_inputs[i]
                hidden_neuron_weight = self.hidden_layer_weights[i]
                sum += hidden_neuron_val * hidden_neuron_weight

        answer = 1 if sum > 0 else -1
        return answer

    def learn(self, inputs, answer):
        assert len(inputs) == self.input_signal_count
        for inp in inputs:
            assert inp in (0, 1)
        assert answer in (-1, 1)

        if self.get_answer(inputs) != answer:
            hidden_layer_values = self.get_hidden_layer_values(inputs)
            print('Hidden layer values: ' + str(hidden_layer_values))
            hidden_neurons_activated = self.calc_activated_hidden_neurons(hidden_layer_values)
            print('Hidden layers active: ' + str(hidden_neurons_activated))
            if True not in hidden_neurons_activated:
                print('Error: no neurons was activated')

            print('Hidden layer weights before: ' + str(self.hidden_layer_weights))

            for i in range(self.hidden_layer_size):
                neuron_activated = hidden_neurons_activated[i]
                if neuron_activated:
                    self.hidden_layer_weights[i] += answer

            print('Hidden layer weights after: ' + str(self.hidden_layer_weights))
        else:
            print('Error: answer was interpreted as correct')
```

Код процесса обучения:

```
data = [(0, 0, 0), (0, 1, 1), (1, 0, 1), (1, 1, 0)]

neural_net = Perceptron(2, 3)
vis = PerceptronVisualizer(neural_net)

def to_bool(integer):
    assert isinstance(integer, int)
    assert integer in (-1, 1)
    return 0 if integer == -1 else 1


def from_bool(boolean):
    assert boolean in (0, 1)
    return 1 if boolean == 1 else -1

def step(data, perceptron):
    for data_sample in data:
        print('Testing: {} ^ {} = {}'.format(data_sample[0], data_sample[1], data_sample[2]))
        perceptron_answer = perceptron.get_answer(data_sample[:2])
        boolean_answer = to_bool(perceptron_answer)
        print('Result: {}'.format(boolean_answer))
        if boolean_answer != data_sample[2]:
            print('Try to learn right answer')
            boolean_input = data_sample[:2]
            integer_answer = from_bool(data_sample[2])
            perceptron.learn(boolean_input, integer_answer)
            integer_answer = perceptron.get_answer(boolean_input)
            boolean_answer = to_bool(integer_answer)
            print('Result after learning: {}'.format(boolean_answer))
            show_perceptron(perceptron)
            prompt_yn('y or n to continue...')

keep_on = True
while keep_on:
    random.shuffle(data)
    step(data, neural_net)
```

Это может являться следствием того, о чём написано в цитате 2?